# How to extract unique permutations from pandas DataSeries?

Tags: python, pandas, jupyter, data-science

Working in Jupyter with Pandas DataSeries I have a dataset with rows like this:

```
color: white
engineType: diesel
make: Ford
manufacturingYear: 2004
accidentCount: 123
```

What I need to do is to plot charts of accident counts (y-axis) by manufacturing year (x-axis) for all permutations of color/engineType/make. Any ideas how to proceed with this?

To speed things up I have this initial setup:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame, Series
import random


colors = ['white', 'black','silver']
engineTypes = ['diesel', 'petrol']
makes = ['ford', 'mazda', 'subaru']
years = range(2000,2005)

rowCount = 100

def randomEl(data):
    rand_items = [data[random.randrange(len(data))] for item in range(rowCount)]
    return rand_items


df = DataFrame({
    'color': Series(randomEl(colors)),
    'engineType': Series(randomEl(engineTypes)),
    'make': Series(randomEl(makes)),
    'year': Series(randomEl(years)),
    'accidents': Series([int(1000*random.random()) for i in range(rowCount)])
})
```

Answer (score 6):

You can get the number of accidents by unique `color`, `engineType`, and `make` combinations using [`groupby()`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html):

```
accident_counts = df.groupby(['color', 'engineType', 'make'])['accidents'].sum()
```

[Matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/) is one way of plotting the results:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
accident_counts.plot(kind='bar')
plt.show()
```

Comment: Great Answer. Amazing how much work pandas does for you.